# adplus - doesn't create dump file, process seems locked up

Tags: crash-dumps, adplus

I'm trying to run:

adplus -Crash -o C:\AdPlusDumps -pn .exe -lcqd

(I've also tried without the -lcqd)

My program throws an exception (normally would crash)

Instead it seems to hang and I can't kill it.  This also happened when I tried using DebugDiag, but not with procdump (this actually creates a dump file).  I'm trying out different tools to test the creation of dump files.  I end up having to to kill the computer to get rid of the process.

using sysinternals handle.exe I can see my program is locked by dbghost.exe

The program is written in c# and uses managed and unmanaged code.

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like the problem was I still had my rule from DebugDiag running.  After removing that, adplus worked fine.  I may have had issues with 64-bit vs 32-bit as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem was I still had my rule from DebugDiag running.

After removing that, adplus worked fine. I may have had issues with 64-bit vs 32-bit as well.